# Seeking advice on building web app that splits datasets

Tags: csv, web-applications

I am looking for guidance on a project I am working on. For reference, I am skilled in HTML, CSS, and pretty familiar with JavaScript, and that's where my coding knowledge stops.
I am attempting to create a web app the allows the following high-level workflow

1. User uploads CSV file via web UI
2. Application splits data of file randomly into two groups
3. Application creates two CSV files, each containing one of the two
   data sets
4. Application surfaces links via the web UI for the user to download
   each of the files

Here is a more specific example:

1. User uploads CSV files with the following dataset '1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10'.
2. Application transforms this into two equally sized random data sets such as: '2, 3, 5, 6, 9' and '1, 4, 7, 8, 10'.
3. Application creates two files. The first containing '2, 3, 5, 6, 9' and the second containing '1, 4, 7, 8, 10'
4. User is presented with two links, 'Dataset 1', and 'Dataset 2', which clicking either initiates a file download.

I am comfortable building the front-end of this, but looking for advice on how to design the backend. Looking for the path of least resistance here and any guidance is appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery-csv](https://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv) will read the file in browser and POST the rows as JSON to the server--only a good option if the files will stay under 5000 rows, because you're making the browser do the brunt of the work. The nice thing about that is your logic for how to split the file can be in JavaScript where you're comfortable. The downside is you'd certainly need a database to store the data until it gets a flag from your JavaScript that the transfer is finished. Then you are responsible for building a file out of that data. If you do that on-demand when they click the link it's going to be slow and heavy on your server.

There's also [jQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) which will submit the file, as an `<input type = "file"/>`. With that you can get away with bigger files and probably get away with no database if the file isn't more than a couple MB. Once the files are written somewhere in your server you can send back a file id. The downside is you're storing files within your app along with the potential security implications of that.

Third option is if the files are huge and/or a lot of people will be uploading, which is to direct their uploads to a storage medium like FTP or  Amazon AWS. Then another, seperate process reads the file, does what it needs to with the data, and then writes the files back to the storage medium. The separate process is responsible for sending back links to the files, either by putting them in a database for that user or sending an email, etc. The advantages here is the files can be gigabytes if you do it right, and it's easiest to scale if you get more users. The down side is you're doing some serious server-side stuff.

Edit: Since that's the direction you're looking, I'll add to that. You'll certainly want two separate applications--your website, which just offloads the file, and then a worker application behind the scenes that streams the file through your logic into two streams that append to your new files. A simple version would be a scheduled one that checks for new files every so often, then moves or deletes them and emails the links to your user. It can be made fancier in increments, such as using Amazon queueing so your website queues a message to the worker that a file is ready, triggering it into action right away rather than waiting for a certain scheduled time. Another would be to use SignalR so the worker can notify the user on the website in real time that 'your files are ready, click here to download them'.

Whatever approach you take, make sure that the link to the file is rather random and long, and not something like an incrementing number or timestamp, or you'll run the risk of some slightly savvy user being able to spy on the files of other users.

Probably your best solution is going to be some combination of the above after weighing the pros and cons.

Comment: thank you so much for the detailed answer. Really informative. Regrettably, I think I need to opt for option #3 as these files may be upwards of 1 million rows of data. I feel comfortable making a simple font-end that allows users to upload files to S3, but notably creating a service that achieves my "parse data, split data, and create new files" requirements is where I am a novice. Any recommendations on how to approach that? Would using Lambda functions be a good approach? Its all new to me, and I'm game for diving in, but just looking for guidance on the path of least resistance.

Comment: I have been looking into this further and I am thinking about doing the following:
- Building simple frontend for users to upload files, which will be routed to S3 bucket
- Create Lambda function(s) in Java that that parses the data set included in the CSV, and then creates two separate files, each with a random set of half the data, and then saves those new files back into S3
- Then surface those links to the new files in the frontend

I am assuming I'll be able to connect some of the dots in that process with SNS topics, or something like that, but still a little fuzzy on it. Thoughts?

Comment: That sounds about right. In that case I added to my answer.